# Qt #include not working with External Library

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, external

I am fairly new to Qt 5 and Qt Creator . I created a library project called D20Controls. I have the D20Controls.lib file. In my project, I want to use classes of my lib D20Controls. So I right-click on my project and do Add Library... I choose External library and I browse up to my D20Controls.Lib file. Now everything seems to be added correctly to my .pro file.

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../build-D20Controls-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug/release/ -lD20Controls
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../build-D20Controls-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug/debug/ -lD20Controls

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../build-D20Controls-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug/debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../build-D20Controls-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug/debug

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../build-D20Controls-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug/release/D20Controls.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../build-D20Controls-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug/debug/D20Controls.lib
```

but when I want to use it in my project 
`#include <D20Controls>` or any .h file in it, I can't compile error like :
...main.cpp:4: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'D20Controls': No such file or directory

How can I do use my lib ? (I have tried static linking and dynamic linking)

What am I missing ?

Comment: The obvious question is, do you have a file called D20Controls.h (or D20Controls without the .h)?. That is what the error is talking about, not the file D20Controls.lib.

Comment: In fact, I don't but is there a way to include to whole library instead of every .h file like

Comment: `#include` is used for including header files - normally suffixed with `.h` or `.hpp`. Which such files does the library provide? You should `#include` those.

Comment: You don't 'include' libraries, you link with them. You only include header files. If you have lots of header files and you want to include all of them, you are going to have to use multiple '#includes'. Unless your library is very big, it probably would have been better to write it with one include file.

Comment: when I #include "d20Controls.h" it won't compile but I have access to the classes defined in d20Controls.h It tells me No such file or directory but the strange thing is that it obviously can find it because I can use the different classes

Comment: @yhcowboy when you say "I can use...", do you mean that Qt Creator autocompletes them and does not give red wavy lines, etc? This is because Qt Creator (or other IDE) and compiler are two different things. Just because one finds the includes, does not mean the other one does.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to solve a problem like this:

1. Find `D20Controls.h` in your file system. If there are several, decide which is the correct one you want to include.
2. Find one actually executed *compile* command (for example one which has `-o main.o` and `main.cpp` in it), there are several but they should normally have same `-I` flags within one project. If you compile from Qt Creator, look in the "Compile Output" tab at the bottom of the screen. If you compile from command line, scroll up or even copy-paste to some editor.
3. See if there is `-I...something...` option on the compile command, which matches the location of correct include file.
4. If not, add or fix it in the `.pro` file, re-run qmake, build.

---

Above applies for finding headers, and `-I` flag for compile command, which specifies include path. If it is linker that complains (which usually happens in case like this, after you fix includes), then find the link command (one with bunch of `.o` files, and something like `-o final-program-name`), and look for `-L` option, which specifies link paths.